# Dropdown menu with full width over parents's width

Tags: css

I'm trying to make full-width dropdown menu.

but width of parents is 1500px, so the dropdown menu can't be full width. (100vw)

is there any solution with it? I tried to put some full-width white DIV section behind of the dropdown content but there's no luck.

I need help :(

Thanks advance for your help.

Here's codepen link.

'https://codepen.io/DOSH360/pen/qBaKKoq'

Comment: Please include code **within the question**. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning is positioned to the **nearest positioned ancestor**. Your nearest positioned ancestor is your container which is taking up 100% of the width of your 1500px navigation.

Change your container from

```css
.container {
  position: relative; /* Absolute Positioning Restraint */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```

to

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I've tested this out and it spans to the full width. I hope I could help :)

If you'd like to learn more about how this works, I'd recommend Mozilla's in-depth article about [Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Thanks! but there is one problem with it. the contents inside of dropdown menu keep changing its position by screen resolution. Is there any solution with it?

Comment: The elements move off of the screen as they are using `margin-left` (`margin-left: 585px`). I can see that you want to center the content, so I would use CSS Flexbox or `margin-auto` instead of positioning your content from the left.